# Alternative for array_agg while keeping all the rows, excluding current row from window

Tags: python, pandas

My table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cid': ['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 'mid': ['1','1','2','2','2','3'], 'date_start': ['2019-05-17', '2020-01-20', '2018-02-10','2019-03-10','2020-03-10', '2018-04-11'], 'date_end': ['2020-05-17', '2021-01-20', '2019-02-10', '2020-03-10', '2021-03-15', '2021-04-11']})
df['date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(testdf['date_start']).dt.date
df['date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(testdf['date_end']).dt.date

span = []

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    span.append((df['date_start'][i], df['date_end'][i]))

df['span'] = pd.Series(span)
```

```
cid mid span
A   1   (2019-05-17, 2020-05-17)
B   1   (2020-01-20, 2021-01-20)
C   2   (2018-02-10, 2019-02-10)
D   2   (2019-03-10, 2020-03-10)
E   2   (2020-03-10, 2021-03-15)
F   3   (2018-04-11, 2021-04-11)
```

What I want: (I want a tuple/list of all the spans of the previous rows for the window in each row. Which should be roughly equivalent to the pgsql query `array_agg(span) over (partition by mid rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)`. How can I do this in python using pandas?)

```
cid mid span                      prev_dates
A   1   (2019-05-17, 2020-05-17)  Null
B   1   (2020-01-20, 2021-01-20)  ((2019-05-17, 2020-05-17))
C   2   (2018-02-10, 2019-02-10)  Null
D   2   (2019-03-10, 2020-03-10)  ((2018-02-10, 2019-02-10))
E   2   (2020-03-10, 2021-03-15)  ((2018-02-10, 2019-02-10), (2019-03-10, 2020-03-10))
F   3   (2018-04-11, 2021-04-11)  Null
```

I tried this: `df.groupby('mid')['span'].transform(lambda x: tuple(x))`, not working as intended. I think there should be a rolling() function added, but this itself is not working where I thought it should at least give the tuple of all the spans for each group.

`df.groupby('mid')['span'].agg(lambda x: tuple(x))` does somewhat like the array_agg function from pgsql, but in this way I'm not getting all the rows. If I use transform, I'm not getting what I want.

Comment: What data type is your "span" column?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible constructor for the DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an accumulation function:

```
def acc(s):
    l = []
    return pd.Series([pd.NA]+[tuple(l:=l+[x]) for x in s[:-1]],
                          index=s.index)

df['prev_dates'] = df.groupby('mid')['span'].apply(acc)
```

Output:

```
  cid mid  date_start    date_end                      span                                            prev_dates
0   A   1  2019-05-17  2020-05-17  (2019-05-17, 2020-05-17)                                                  <NA>
1   B   1  2020-01-20  2021-01-20  (2020-01-20, 2021-01-20)                           ((2019-05-17, 2020-05-17),)
2   C   2  2018-02-10  2019-02-10  (2018-02-10, 2019-02-10)                                                  <NA>
3   D   2  2019-03-10  2020-03-10  (2019-03-10, 2020-03-10)                           ((2018-02-10, 2019-02-10),)
4   E   2  2020-03-10  2021-03-15  (2020-03-10, 2021-03-15)  ((2018-02-10, 2019-02-10), (2019-03-10, 2020-03-10))
5   F   3  2018-04-11  2021-04-11  (2018-04-11, 2021-04-11)                                                  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
df["prev_dates"] = [
    window.to_list()[:-1]
    for window in df.groupby("mid")["span"].expanding()
]
```

The `groupby(...).expanding(...)` does almost the same thing as the original `PARTITION BY ... BETWEEN ... AND ...` in pgsql. An expanding window always contains the current row so we simply exclude the last row from the result set.

Comment: It worked, but there's some weird thing happening. I checked some rows where the issues happened:
`for i,window in enumerate(df.groupby("mid")["span"].expanding()):
    if i >= 2480 and i <= 2486: 
        print(window)`
So after row 2483, it all gets messed up. All the rows have non null mid and span values though
`2479    (2019-05-01, 2020-05-01)
2480    (2020-05-01, 2021-05-01)
2481    (2021-05-01, 2022-05-01)
2482    (2021-08-01, 2022-05-01)
2483    (2022-05-01, 2023-05-01)
Name: span, dtype: object
3025    (2021-08-30, 2022-03-01)
Name: span, dtype: object`

Comment: Somehow, there's no window being created for row 2484 upto 3024, even though all the rows have non null mid and span values.

Comment: And also, the approach by @mozway doesn't have this issue. What could be the reason?